# Is this symbol a TVS diode, and what is the purpose of a TVS diode?

Tags: diodes, tvs

I'm looking at two similar diodes in a wiring diagram. These diode symbols do not match any of the common diode symbols.

The purpose of D2 seems to be pulling to ground. These diodes somewhat resemble a TVS diode, but it would be great to get some affirmation about that. It would be helpful to also get some information about the purpose of a TVS diode and what these diodes do in this drawing.

I included the standard ground to chassis symbol in the drawing below, but the actual symbol in the schematic drawing was a solid circle with a horizontal line across the bottom of the circle.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Look up "zener diode symbol". D2 will conduct when the voltage exceeds the zener voltage plus D2 forward drop. D1 will never conduct because the drawn circuit is incomplete.

Comment: No, there is no TVS diode in your schematic. You have 3 regular PN junction diodes, and 2 Zener diodes in your circuit.

Comment: I think everyone has missed that the diagram is representative, "these diode symbols do not match any of the common diode symbols" -- unfortunately this makes the Circuitlab diagram useless as it only contains the standard ones. We need to see the original, or enough of it to be able to tell what the components are. Diodes around relay coils are at least suggestive of what's shown here, but we can't know for certain that's what you're looking at.

Comment: The diodes from circuit lab were used to exactly recreate those diodes in question from the Yamaha schematic.  The circuit lab drawing was not a complete representation of the Yamaha schematic.  The question was only related to the use of these diodes in anti-series.  The Bing AI suggested these diodes in this sequence were similar to a TVS diode - something I was not familiar with.  The impressive answer from Simon Fitch provided the information I as looking for.  Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's describe and compare regular diodes and zener diodes, first, to make sure we are on the same page.

A regular silicon diode, when forward biased, will have +0.7V across it (its anode will be +0.7V higher in potential than its cathode). This is when current flows through it in the direction indicated by the diode symbol's "arrow".

All diodes have some "breakdown" voltage, which determines the potential difference between anode and cathode at which it begins conducting, when *reverse biased* (its anode has a *lower* potential than the cathode). Typically, for a regular silicon diode, the voltage required for conduction to occur could be -50V, or more negative. If you employ a regular diode, then it is assumed you *never* want reverse breakdown to occur in that device, since that's when current flows in the "wrong" direction through the diode.

The difference between a regular diode and a zener diode is that for zener diodes the reverse bias voltage at which it begins to conduct is very well defined, and deliberately chosen to be some comparatively low value, such as -12V. You use a zener diode only when you *require* the diode to begin conducting when reverse biased to some particular potential difference. When forward biased (anode potential is higher than cathode), a zener diode behaves like a regular diode, current flows almost unimpeded, and the diode has +0.7V across it.

Let's assume the zener diodes in all cases in the context of this question are rated at 12V. Such a diode will conduct in both directions, but will need its anode to be +0.7V higher than its cathode (forward biased), or its anode to be -12V relative to cathode potential.

This can be visualised with an example. On the left below (circuit A), is a voltage source sweeping from -20V to +20V, applied across a zener diode D1 and resistor R1 (to limit current; when that diode conducts it will conduct *really* well, and we need to keep current under control somehow):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxdHeu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now let's plot node Z's potential (as measured by VM1) over the entire voltage range:

[image]

Here's is current through D1, as measured by AM1:

[image]

As you can see, current is zero (D1 is not conducting) while the voltage across it is between −12V and +0.7V. It begins to conduct strongly outside those bounds, so strongly that it actually prevents \$V_Z\$ from straying outside these limits. This behaviour is often called "clamping, which is the term I will use from now on. Here we would say that D1 "clamps" Z to maximum of +0.7V, and a minimum of -12V.

Now compare that behaviour to a regular diode D2, as shown in circuit B. Again the sweep is \$-20V < V_S < 20V\$. Diode voltage \$V_Y\$ then current below:

[image]

[image]

The regular diode never conducts when reverse biased, but still clamps to a a maximum of +0.7V.

A unipolar TVS diode is really just a zener diode designed to withstand very large surge currents for a short time. Such TVS devices have behaviour shown for D1 in circuit A. By flipping D1 upside down, you can clamp voltages to be within \$-0.7V < V_Z < +12V\$ instead.

---

It happens sometimes that we wish to clamp to -12V, but *not* to +0.7V. A single zener diode will not suffice, since it clamps to both bounds. We can combine a regular diode and a zener diode in anti-series, as shown in circuit C below. The idea is to use the regular diode D3 to prevent *forward* current through zener diode D4. In this way, D3 permits current to flow in *reverse* through D4, but will block *all forward current* through D4.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmtzMl.png)</sup>

Here's \$V_W\$ as \$V_S\$ is swept from −20V to +20V, clearly showing node W is clamped to a minimum of −12.7V, but not imposing any constraint on W for potentials above that:

[image]

The lower bound is now −12.7V, not −12V. This is because \$V_W\$ will be the sum of the reverse zener voltage of D4, and the forward voltage of D3.

By flipping both diodes upside down (as in circuit D), behaviour under forward and reverse currents is swapped. Thus we set the *upper* bound instead, to +12.7V. This is shown in circuit D, which behaves like this:

[image]

Circuit E consists of two back-to-back zener diodes, D7 and D8. This has the effect of clamping to a minimum of -12.7V and maximum of +12.7V. For currents in either direction, one of the diodes is forward biased with 0.7V across it, while the other is reverse biased with 12V across it. This means that in either case, the total voltage across the pair cannot exceed \$0.7V + 12V=12.7V\$, negative or positive:

[image]

Bipolar (bi-directional) TVS devices are effectively such back-to-back (ant-series) zener diodes, built to physically withstand large surge currents for a short time.

---

The takeaway from all this is that a diode, or pair of diodes, can never have a voltage \$V_D\$ across it outside of certain bounds. For a single regular diode, this is constraint is:

$$ V_D < +0.7V $$

For a single zener diode rated \$V_Z\$ this is:

$$ -V_Z < V_D < +0.7V $$

For a regular diode in anti-series with a zener diode:

$$ -(V_Z + 0.7) < V_D $$

To see what this means in the context of your circuit, allow me to annotate it with some node names:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBelvv.png)</sup>

D1 and D4 prevent node P from becoming more than 12.7V more positive than Q:

$$ V_P < V_Q + 12.7V $$
$$ V_P - V_Q < 12.7V $$

D2 and D5 prevent node S from rising further than +12.7V above ground (0V):

$$ V_S < 12.7V $$

D3 prevents node S from becoming more than +0.7V more positive than R:

$$ V_S < V_R + 0.7V $$
$$ V_S - V_R < 0.7V $$

---

By connecting a zener diode and regular diode back-to-back across a relay coil (as is the case for RLY2) , the goal is to allow back-EMF (when coil current is cut off) to rise to a much greater voltage than a single regular diode (see RLY1) would allow.

Current through the diodes in both cases rises to the same level initially (due to coil inductance), but power dissipated in diode/diodes will be different. In the single-diode case (RLY1) power will be \$P=0.7V \times I\$, but with the zener in place (RLY2) this rises to \$P=12.7V \times I\$.

Since the magnetic energy stored in the coil's core is being dissipated more quickly for RLY2, that relay will de-actuate (contacts open) much faster.